# javascript substring help

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, substring

I have a string "2500 - SomeValue". How can I remove everything before the 'S' in 'SomeValue'?

```
var x = "2500 - SomeValue";
var y = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf(" - "),
// this is where I'm stuck, I need the rest of the string starting from here.
```

Thanks for any help.

~ck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add 3 (the length of " - ") to the last index and leave off the second parameter. The default when you pass one parameter to substring is the go to the end of the string

```
var y = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf(" - ") + 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's just:

```
var y = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf(" - ") + 3);
```

When you omit the second parameter, it just gives you everything to the end of the string.

EDIT: Since you wanted everything from *after* the " - " I've added 3 to the starting point in order to skip those characters.

Comment: In the question, he asked for everything from the "S" on, cutting out the " - " part. Of course, the code agrees with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
x.substring(x.lastIndexOf(" - "),x.length-1); //corrected
```

Comment: This will actually cause a runtime error because `x.length` is past the end of the string. I think you meant `x.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var y = x.split(" ",2);
```

then you'll have an array of substrings. The third one y[2] will be what you need.

Comment: When you use ‘split(' ', 2)’, you will end up with an array of maximum 2 elements, and if there are 2 or more spaces, the rest will be thrown away... so this doesn't work for the above example. You're trying to use ‘String.split(..., maximum)’ as if it worked sensibly like in Python; unfortunately JavaScript is not sensible.

Comment: An alternative to using the broken split-maximum feature would be, say: “x.split(' - ').slice(1).join(' - ')”, to put back any additional ‘ - ’ strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var y = x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf(' - ') + 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

var y = x.slice(x.lastIndexOf(" - "), x.length - 1);

This will return the value as a string no matter that value is or how long it is and it has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: doesn't slice allow -1 as equivalent to x.length-1?

Comment: slice requires a terminal value.  If the string is of variable length then that is how you find its length for static measurement.  A value of -1 would not work, because as an index the value -1 returns undefined.  In this case that would likely throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var y = x.slice(x.lastIndexOf("-")+2);
```

Usually, we don't have space so we write `+1` but in your case `+2` works fine.